# .net Interop.Word insert from docx without screwing up formatting

Tags: c#, vb.net, ms-word, office-interop

I have an issue I've stuck with for over a year now. I made a Forms application in VB.net which allows the user to type in some information and select items which represent docx-files with tables with special formatting, pictures and other formatting quirks in them.

At the end the software creates a Word document via Office.Interop, using the information the user provided in text fields in the Forms and the items they selected (e.g. it creates a table in Word, listing the user's selections with some extra info) and then appends the content from multiple docx-files depending on the user's selection to the document created via Interop.

The problem is: To achieve this I had to use a pretty dirty method:
I open the respective docx-files, select all content (Range.Wholestory()) and copy it (Range.Copy()). Then I insert this content from the clipboard into my newly created document with the following option:

```
Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
```

This produces a satisfactory result but it feels super dirty since it uses the user's clipboard (which I save at the beginning of the runtime and restore at the end).

I originally tried to use the Selection.InsertFile-Method and tried this again today but it completely screws the formatting.

When the content of the docx is inserted this way it neither has the formatting of the original docx nor the one of the file I created with the program. E.g. the SpaceBefore and SpaceAfter values are wrong, even if I explicitly define them in my created file. Changing the formatting afterwards is no option since the source files contain a lot of special formatting and can change all the time.

Another factor which makes it hard: I cannot save the file before it is presented to the user, using temp folder is not an option in the environment this application is deployed into, so basically everything happens in RAM.

**Summary:**

Basically what I want is to create the same outcome as with my "Copy and Paste" method utilizing the OriginalFormatting WITHOUT using the clipboard. The problem is, the InsertFile-Method doesn't provide an option for the formatting.

Any idea or help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**

The FormattedText option as suggested by Rich Michaels produces the same result as the InsertFile-Method. Here is the relevant part of what I did (word is the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application):

```
#Opening the source file
Dim doctemp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document
doctemp = word.Documents.Open(doctempfilepath)

#Selecting whole document; this is what I did for the "Copy/Paste"-Method, too
doctemp.Range.WholeStory()

Dim insert_range As wordoptions.Range
doc_destination.Activate()

#Jumping to the end and selecting the range
word.Selection.EndKey(Unit:=Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdUnits.wdStory)
insert_range = word.Selection.Range

#Inserting the text
insert_range.FormattedText = doctemp.Range.FormattedText

doctemp.Close(False)
```

This is the problem:
[image: picture of the problem]

Comment: The issue is probably the style definitions: When Word brings together content from two sources and both use the same style names, the style definitions in the target will be applied to the in-coming content by default. The document you're generating: what's its starting point? Do you just use Documents.Add or do you specify a template? My thought would be to define a set of styles in this document with unique names so that Word brings across the original styles.

Comment: The big problem would be if everything is formatted with "Normal", though... Especially if the various files you're pulling in from use different formatting in the same style names...

Comment: @CindyMeister I just use Documents.Add on the original document. I don't get why it works with the PasteAndFormat/wdFormatOriginalFormatting method. Do you have a link to how to define a set of styles? I'm not an expert in that regard though I understand that if I don't define a style it takes the Normal one. So when I insert with PasteandFormat it copies the Formatting from the source together with the content, right?

Comment: `wdOriginalFormatting` should create new styles if the same style name is coming in, or at least convert the formatting to "direct" formatting, overriding the style formatting. I don't have a link for you - I've been doing this for over twenty-five years so my "sources of wisdom" no longer exist, I fear... If you're familiar with CSS that's a good basis for the logic involved. How to work with styles is more an end-user topic... For the near future, I'd say go with what you have, research the styles approach (with a template for new docs, preferably) and implement when you have a chance.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I'll look into it. I mean I get the concept of style sheets but I always thought if I insert the content from a range it does that automatically. I'll try to find out how to export the styles from the source and get it into the destination.

Comment: Exporting styles... not so much. It's possible to "read" them from a Range (`Range.Style`), get the definition, create a new style in the target using that defintion. But creating a unique set of styles in a template file (or using your code) will be more efficient...

Comment: Ah ok, now I get you. Well I agree, using a fixed template would be great but the documents I have to append to my generated one are user generated and I have no control over the styles they use. So I have to go with what I got. But thank you very much nevertheless, I will try a few more things out and if I don't get it to work I have to fall back to my original method.

Comment: How is "wordoptions" declared? You use it in the declare of "insert_range". I would have expected that statement to read ... Dim insert_range as Word.Range

Answer (score 0):

Use the Range.FormattedText property. It doesn't touch the clipboard and it maintains the source formatting. The process is ...

Set the range in the Source document you want "copied" and set the insertion point in the Destination document and then,

```
DestinationRange.FormattedText = SourceRange.FormattedText
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the probem persists. Maybe I'm doing something else fundamentally wrong. I added some additional information and the relevant code fragment + a screenshot of the problem. It's basically the same as with the InsertFile...